# Can i only see xmlHttpRequest errors in firebug in firefox

Tags: firefox, web, firebug, development-environment

In the firebug i can see all `xmlHttprequests` if i check the it in the console options like this

[image]

But my site  has many js files like 40 and i have to scroll down to see if i get any ajax error in get in red color.

Is there any way to just get those error only.

I tried javascript errors but dont catch any erorr in GET request

Answer (score 1):

That may not answer exactly to your needs, but here is how I usually proceed.

Use the Net panel, and use the "XHR" filter, and then sort by "status".

Every requests that have a status >= 400 have failed. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Thus every XHR errors are gathered at the bottom.

[image]

Florent